# "if" statement parameters not functioning as intended. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

The following JavaScript *"if"* statement is not reading the parameters as I intended both parameters to be read. When I shoot *bulletOne* with a function that uses an interval to run **bulletOneLeft++;** the left CSS property of *bulletOne* increases by 1 with each interval as intended. However, when I coded the following *if* statement to detect the CSS style.left property of the *bulletOne* and compare it to the CSS style.left property of an element called "**targetBox**"; the code does not recognize the difference of the CSS style.left properties of these two elements. My question is how can I make this *if* statement execute once bulletOne's CSS style.left property is greater than targetBox's CSS style.left property numerically?

```
if (bulletOneLeft > targetLeftProp){
document.getElementById("targetBox").style.opacity = "0";   
};
```

The two parameters of ***bulletOneLeft*** and ***targetLeftProp*** are described with the following code;

***bulletOneLeft;***

```
#bulletOne {
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
height: 1px;
width: 6px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
bulletOne.style.left = bulletOneLeft;
```

***targetLeftProp;***

```
#targetBox{
position: absolute;
background-color: green;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
top: 30px;
left: 310px;
opacity: 1;
}
var targetLeftProp = window.getComputedStyle(CSSelement, 
null).getPropertyValue("left");
```

***PREVIOUS FAILED ATTEMPT;***
I have tried many different combinations of code, the following was my first failed attempt. The following code seemed the most logical at the time;

```
var bulletLeft = document.getElementById("bulletOne").style.left;
var targetLeft = document.getElementById("targetBox").style.left;

if (bulletOneLeft > targetLeft){
   document.getElementById("targetBox").style.opacity = "0";   
};
```

Comment: Your variable name isn't correct into the last piece of code.Your variable is named bulletLeft and you do the if with bulletOneLeft instead of bulletLeft. If you fix that, it'll probably works :)

Comment: `.style.left` returns a string, not an integer

Comment: In response to @guest271314, you have to use parseFloat https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you made a typo that is why it doesnt work in your failed attemps.

Your variable is named `bulletOne` but you do your if statement with `bulletOneLeft`.

Also :

```
style.left;
```

return a string, so you have to do use parseFloat function or parseInt if you're sure it will always be an int (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) as following :

```
var bulletOne = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bulletOne").style.left;
```

And you are good to go I believe.

Comment: thankyou, i didn't use a typo in the actual code, just in the question; but the parse float is what i needed thx buddy

Comment: Enjoy, mind if I ask if this "game" (what it seems to be) will be released somewhere or made public somehow ? Could be fun to the what you're doing :)

Comment: its simply a project im working on, its very basic, email me at hoyos.a.german@gmail.com and ill send the entire code to you.