# JavaScript NaN error when trying to detect CSS property "left"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, nan

This question piggy backs off of a question I asked yesterday. That question was:

["if" statement parameters not functioning as intended. JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301434/if-statement-parameters-not-functioning-as-intended-javascript/43301511?noredirect=1#comment73668595_43301511)

But now i'm Getting a **NaN** error when I implement the following code:

```
var targetBoxLeft = parseFloat(document.getElementById("targetBox").style.left);
bulletOne.style.left = bulletOneLeft;

if (bulletOneLeft > targetBoxLeft){
document.getElementById("targetBox").style.opacity = "0";   
};
```

Yesterday I didn't use "parseFloat", however my question is, if i'm specifically describing the parameter of targetBoxLeft as a CSS style.left property; why wouldn't that be a specific number? and why wouldn't it take on the number of left: 310px; as specified by the elements properties itself?

```
#targetBox{
position: absolute;
background-color: green;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
top: 30px;
left: 310px;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Logically should the following 2 lines of code detect ACTUAL numbers?;

```
var bulletOneLeft = bulletOne.style.left;
var targetBoxLeft = targetBox.style.left;
```

And then once the above variables are detected as actual numbers, should the following ***if*** statement code be able to compare them depending on their values at any given time if movement(**bulletOneLeft++;**) is involved?:

```
if (bulletOneLeft > targetBoxLeft){
document.getElementById("targetBox").style.opacity = "0";   
};
```

Im not exactly sure whats happening but since i'm getting a NaN error for when targetBox.style.left is read by the code i'm guessing that maybe a CSS property needs additional code to be converted into an actual number/variable before I run the *if* statement with corresponding **VAR's**?

Comment: Maybe the script loads first before the CSS not sure or try accessing any other property

Comment: if i take "px" out it still treats it as a "string" -  isn't 310 a number? not trying to be sarcastic, i genuinely mean isn't the property of css style.left 310 an actual number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are querying the `.style.left` property, which is not the same as computed style. `.style` property of element references `style` attribute value. `parseFloat("")` returns `NaN`. Use `window.getComputedStyle()`

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
console.log(div.style.left, parseFloat(div.style.left));
console.log(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue("left")));
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  left:310px;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
```

Comment: hmm gna implement, ill let you know if it works in 5 mins

Comment: I think this is the proper answer, but im having a difficult time implementing it. i will continue to experiment and comment if i crack it.

Comment: _"but im having a difficult time implementing it"_ What do you mean specifically? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7hm1jrvw/ for some reason my purple box doesnt move or shoot the three bullets like it does in chrome. but thats not the issue, the If statement isnt comparing the bullets x axis to the green box's x axis

Comment: _"like it does in chrome"_ Which line of code and browser are you referencing?

Comment: line 62 of the JavaScript code. I wrote it with the intent of comparing the bullets x axis with the green box x axis. in my browser when i run this code, the moment i hit space bar it shoots a bullet, the bullet travels to the end of the game grid. but i wanted it to compare the X axis of the bullet and the stationary green box so that i can start to implement target detection

Comment: You did not implement approach at Answer at jsfiddle at lines `29`, and `30`? `targetBoxLeft` is still a string at `if` statement block https://jsfiddle.net/7hm1jrvw/1/

Comment: yes i used parsefloat from another answer and also i implemented this answer of 
  
  console.log(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue("left")));

Comment: i even replaced div with "targetBox" since thats the element in question

Comment: Where? Why is `targetBoxLeft` an empty string at `if` statement block following the line you referenced? See `console` at linked jsfiddle at previous comment.

Comment: thats my question exactly. when i implemented the answer given, there was no change to behavior.

Comment: Where did you implement `window.getComputedStyle()` as to `targetBoxLeft` variable at linked jsfiddle? `window.getComputedStyle()` is not implemented at line `30` `var targetBoxLeft = document.getElementById("targetBox").style.left;`

Comment: its not in the jsfiddle link, i didnt link it because it didnt work when i implemented it, dont want to go down a rabbit whole of not working code with compounded not working code

Comment: _"its not in the jsfiddle link"_ ? That is what asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310034/javascript-nan-error-when-trying-to-detect-css-property-left/43310217?noredirect=1#comment73685334_43310217 ; that is, where implementation did not return expected result? _"dont want to go down a rabbit whole of not working code with compounded not working code"_ You can adjust code in portions, then move to next portion when certain returning expected result, instead of attempting to solve the entire piece of code at once.

Comment: `"targetBox"` is not an `html` element at `var targetBox = document.querySelector("targetBox");`, you also overwrite previous assigned value of `targetBox` variable `var targetBox = document.getElementById("targetBox");`. Also, element reference should be passed to `window.getComputedStyle()`, not a string, at `(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle("targetBox").getPropertyValue("left")));` https://jsfiddle.net/7hm1jrvw/3/

Comment: Wow thx so much, i am going to read this very carefully because it is a bit complex, but i think once i get a solid understanding of what you did, it will help me with the rest of this project. THANKS!